# Zend_Db not found

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
use Zend\Db;

$db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', array(
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname'   => 'test'
));
```

I'am trying to require Zend_Db by the keyword 'use', but i get An error that there are not class Zend_Db, what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: fourth question about zendframework database... I really suggest you read some tutorials or a book.

Comment: i don't have time right now, need to do it fast, as always stackoverflow is the savior

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ZF1, then the class is `Zend_Db`. In this case, if you really want to use PHP 5.3 namespaces, then the correct usage is:

```
use \Zend_Db;

$db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', array(
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname'   => 'test'
));
```

If you are using ZF2, then the relevant component is `Zend\Db`, but creating adapters there is typically done using [factories defined in module config](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/database-and-models.html).

And, as noted elsewhere, figuring out autoloading makes life a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

add this at beginning of file

```
   require_once 'Zend/Db.php';
```

Comment: read this similar document... http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/what-is-missing-in-the-this-simple-Zend-DB-code-td3352982.html

Answer (score 1):

Zend Framework 1.x predates PHP namespaces by some time. As a result ZF1 is not really friendly to things like the `use` keyword. If you need to use components of Zend Framework 1.x you will likely be better served by using the included [autoloader component](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html).

If you are using the framework as an MVC application then this whole thing is moot and I recommend you take some time and learn how the default configuration works. Because if you're using ZF1 as an MVC the `Zend_Db` component will already be on the autoloader.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix underscore names with slashes

```
use Zend_Db as Db

$db = Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', array(
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname'   => 'test'
));
```